# How to calculate all possible combinations of values to cover dynamic amount?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, permutation

I am attempting to return all the possible unique combinations of ‘piping’ needed to at least cover the amount of feet provided.

This problem is similar to common coin change algorithms.

Pipes come in increments of 10', 25', and 50'.

I’ve looked at examples from [here](http://jgpettibone.github.io/coin-sums/) and [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-7-coin-change/) which seem to be close, however, I’d like to return all the possible combination not simply count them.

Here’s is my current code:

```
 let allCombos = [];
  let pipeAmounts = [50, 25, 10];

  function findPiping (feet, index, combo) {
    if (index > pipeAmounts-1) {
      return;
    }
    let makeCombos = (amountOfFeet, index, combo) => {
      let currentPipe = pipeAmounts[index];
      let newFeet = amountOfFeet - currentPipe;

      combo.push(currentPipe);

      if (newFeet >= currentPipe) {
        makeCombos(newFeet, index, combo);
      }

      if (newFeet < currentPipe && newFeet > 0) {
        makeCombos(newFeet, index, combo);

      }
      if (newFeet < 0) {
        allCombos.push(combo);
        combo = [];
        makeCombos(feet, index+1, combo);
      }
    };
    makeCombos(feet, index, combo);
  }
  findPiping(60, 0, []);
  console.log('allCombos', allCombos)
```

Currently my code only produces only 2 combinations.

How can I find all possible combinations that cover the amount of feet needed?

Comment: Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
You've shown no output from this code, nor have you specified your problem: "I’m having trouble wrapping my mind around it" is not a problem specification.  That suggests a local tutor, not SO.

Comment: I have modified the post presenting an output.  The question 'How can I find all possible combinations that cover the amount of feet needed?'  is clear.

Comment: I just installed Node v0.12.0 to work on this.  It claims a syntax error: `(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) {  let allCombos =
                                                                   ^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
`.  What version are you using?

Comment: I was just running it in chrome as part of a webpage.  Though I verified I have no issues with node v6.11.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a recursion that returns all valid combinations that cover at least the required `feet`, given an unlimited choice of increments presented in `amounts`.

```js
function f(feet, amounts, i, combo){
  if (feet <= 0 || i == amounts.length)
    return [combo];
  
  if (i == amounts.length - 1){
    while (feet > 0){
      combo.push(amounts[i]);
      feet -= amounts[i];
    }
    return [combo];
  }

  let combos = f(feet, amounts, i+1, combo.slice());

  while (feet > 0){
    combo.push(amounts[i]);

    feet -= amounts[i];

    combos = combos.concat(
      f(feet, amounts, i+1, combo.slice())
    );
  }
  
  return combos;
}

let pipes = [50, 25, 10];

console.log(JSON.stringify(f(60, pipes, 0, [])));
```

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you.